# Is it possible to use both GET and POST in a same method?

Tags: c#, wcf, rest

I would like to know, in a wcf rest service is it possible to use both HTTP POST and HTTP Get in same method? I mean to say that a client page can either use post or get to invoke my method.

My client wants me to implement a method in this way.

> As our API is a "RESTful" service we should be able to use both GET
>   and POST with this method. The parameter can be placed in the URL
>   of a GET request and also in the Header section of the GET request. When
>   using a HTTP POST with this method the parameter can be
>   stored in the header section or the body.

Is it possible?

Comment: part of the job is to try. so...go for it

Comment: Thats not very REST. if you use them both at once POST isnt really doing what it says

Comment: Yes, it is possible but `POST` and `GET` both method have different meaning so using on the same method would be meaningless.

Comment: I have edited my question to explain it properly. Please take a look.

Comment: Did you mean something like `<form action="home.aspx?var1=0" >`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets do it by writing code! Suppose you have a method!

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "Leads",
ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
[WebGet(UriTemplate="/Leads")]
Result AddLeads(ReqLead[] rl); // This is our method.
```

When you will run your service, it will compiled and run successfully and browser will display you a page.

[image: Service]

Now green arrow pointing is my Service name. By cliking on it will redirect you an error page and it will make an idea clear to you! See the image below.

[image: Error]

I hope it will give you an idea. Moreover! In you `[OperationContract]` you will define only one method type, whether **GET** or **POST**. You can't have both.

Thanks

Comment: So, "As our API is a "RESTful" service we should be able to use both GET and POST with this method. The parameter can be placed in the URL of a GET request and also in the Header section of the GET request. When using a HTTP POST with this method the parameter can be stored in the header section or the body." will not be possible?

Comment: http://keshksoftwareskill.wordpress.com/2012/01/06/consume-same-api-with-multi-method-get-post-in-rest-wcf/ This link says define two methods with the same UriTemplate as. Is this a best way?

Comment: Hmm!!! Then you can try this! I understood your question as "is it possible to use both HTTP POST and HTTP Get in same method?", so for same method it is not possible but yes you can use same UriTemplate for GET and POST. And it depends on your request type whether it is GET or POST.